# WPF restoring position in the Combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, streamreader

There is an `Observablecollection Fathers` that stores the ID-Firstname-Lastname father. How to make it so that when loading data from the child.lbs file, the `ID` value that is written in the file under `word[4]` is selected in the Combobox field? Item values are spelled out using XAML `<Combobox "ItemsSource = {Binding Fathers}"/>`

*That is, so that when the file is loaded, the same values are restored as they were before the shutdown (the so-called Save/Load)*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atvvx.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcWjh.png)

Father.cs

```cs
namespace LabelBase.Models
{
    public class Father : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private int _id;
        public int FatherID
        {
            get => _id;
            set
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _firstname;
        public string Firstname
        {
            get => _firstname;
            set
            {
                _firstname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _secondname;
        public string Secondname
        {
            get => _secondname;
            set
            {
                _secondname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

Child.cs

```cs
namespace LabelBase.Models
{
    public class Child : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _id;
        public int ChildID
        {
            get => _id;
            set
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _first;
        public string Firstname
        {
            get => _first;
            set
            {
                _first = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _second;
        public string Secondname
        {
            get => _second;
            set
            {
                _second = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Father _father;
        public Father Father
        {
            get => _father;
            set
            {
                _father = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

`child.lbs` contents:

```
13;Ken;Hollow;83
10;Fill;Kenory;93
```

`father.lbs` contents:

```
83;Frank;Malkov
93;Jack;Miles
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Save">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Save" Margin="100" Height="50" Command="{Binding SaveButton}"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Load" Margin="100" Height="50" Command="{Binding LoadButton}"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Child">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,50" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="25" Margin="5" Text="{Binding ElementName=ChildGrid, Path=Columns[0].Header, StringFormat={}{0}: }" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="25" Margin="5" Text="{Binding ElementName=ChildGrid, Path=Columns[1].Header, StringFormat={}{0}: }" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Height="25" Margin="5" Text="{Binding ElementName=ChildGrid, Path=Columns[2].Header, StringFormat={}{0}: }" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Height="25" Margin="5" Text="{Binding ElementName=ChildGrid, Path=Columns[3].Header, StringFormat={}{0}: }" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="25" Text="{Binding SelectedChildren.ChildID}" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="25" Text="{Binding SelectedChildren.Firstname}" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="25" Text="{Binding SelectedChildren.Secondname}" Margin="5"/>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Fathers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChildren.Father}" Margin="5">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                                <Binding Path="Firstname"/>
                                                <Binding Path="Secondname"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                    <DataGrid Name="ChildGrid" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChildren}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ChildID}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Firstname" Binding="{Binding Firstname}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Secondname" Binding="{Binding Secondname}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Father" Binding="{Binding Father.FatherID}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <Button Height="25" Margin="10,0,10,20" Content="Add Child" Command="{Binding AddChildButton}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Father">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,50" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="25" Margin="5" Text="{Binding ElementName=FatherGrid, Path=Columns[0].Header, StringFormat={}{0}: }" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="25" Margin="5" Text="{Binding ElementName=FatherGrid, Path=Columns[1].Header, StringFormat={}{0}: }" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Height="25" Margin="5" Text="{Binding ElementName=FatherGrid, Path=Columns[2].Header, StringFormat={}{0}: }" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="25" Text="{Binding SelectedFathers.FatherID}" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="25" Text="{Binding SelectedFathers.Firstname}" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="25" Text="{Binding SelectedFathers.Secondname}" Margin="5"/>

                    </Grid>
                    <DataGrid Name="FatherGrid" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Fathers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFathers}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding FatherID}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Firstname" Binding="{Binding Firstname}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Secondname" Binding="{Binding Secondname}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <Button Height="25" Margin="10,0,10,20" Content="Add Father" Command="{Binding AddFatherButton}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
```

ContextVIew.cs:

```cs
using LabelBase.Models;

namespace LabelBase
{
    public class ContextView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Father> Fathers { get; }
        public ObservableCollection<Child> Children { get; }

        private Father _selectedFather;
        public Father SelectedFathers
        {
            get => _selectedFather;
            set
            {
                _selectedFather = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand _addFatherButton;
        public RelayCommand AddFatherButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _addFatherButton ?? (_addFatherButton = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    Father f = new Father();
                    Random r = new Random();

                    f.FatherID = r.Next(99);
                    Fathers.Insert(Fathers.Count, f);
                    SelectedFathers = f;
                }));
            }
        }

        private Child _selectedChild;
        public Child SelectedChildren
        {
            get => _selectedChild;
            set
            {
                _selectedChild = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand _addChildButton;
        public RelayCommand AddChildButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _addChildButton ?? (_addChildButton = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    Child c = new Child();
                    Random r = new Random();

                    c.ChildID = r.Next(99);
                    Children.Insert(Children.Count, c);
                    SelectedChildren = c;
                }));
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand _save;
        public RelayCommand SaveButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _save ?? (_save = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    StreamWriter swChild = new StreamWriter($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/save/child.lbs", false);
                    StreamWriter swFather = new StreamWriter($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/save/father.lbs", false);

                    foreach(Child item in Children)
                    {
                        string sandwich = $"{item.ChildID};{item.Firstname};{item.Secondname};{item.Father.FatherID}";
                        swChild.WriteLine(sandwich);
                    }
                    swChild.Close();
                    foreach (Father item in Fathers)
                    {
                        string sandwich = $"{item.FatherID};{item.Firstname};{item.Secondname}";
                        swFather.WriteLine(sandwich);
                    }
                    swFather.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Complete");
                    
                }));
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand _load;
        public RelayCommand LoadButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _load ?? (_load = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    StreamReader srChild = new StreamReader($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/save/child.lbs", false);
                    StreamReader srFather = new StreamReader($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/save/father.lbs", false);

                    string lineChild, lineFather;

                    while((lineFather = srFather.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] word = lineFather.Split(';');
                        Father f = new Father();
                        f.FatherID = int.Parse(word[0]);
                        f.Firstname = word[1];
                        f.Secondname = word[2];
                        Fathers.Insert(Fathers.Count, f);
                    }
                    
                    while((lineChild = srChild.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] word = lineChild.Split(';');
                        Child c = new Child();
                        c.ChildID = int.Parse(word[0]);
                        c.Firstname = word[1];
                        c.Secondname = word[2];
                        //c.Father.FatherID = int.Parse(word[3]);

                        Children.Insert(Children.Count, c);
                    }
                    srChild.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Complete");
                }));
            }
        }

        public ContextView(){

            Fathers = new ObservableCollection<Father>();
            Children = new ObservableCollection<Child>();

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

*There is a Project: https://github.com/RodKingroo/FatherChild*

Who will help, thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by combobox status and what is Children? How is this mysterious ComboBox linked to the posted code? Please add more context that helps to understand your problem...

Comment: `Children.Insert(Children.Count, c);` is equivalent to `Children.Add(c);`. Also consider to use the async API of StreamReader.

Comment: @BionicCode I don't think all the code will fit here, that's why I left the link to project in GitHub
I mean, I need to make it so that when you click on LoadButton, it should display the results that were when saving. 
I don't have enough brains to explain * I haven't slept for 3 days =B*
I'll try it now.
We have 2 models. `Father` and `Child`
In `Child`, I introduced the variable `public Father Father`, with properties. And using XAML, I indicated that `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fathers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChildren.Father}"/>`

Comment: @BionicCode 
Data is stored in `Observablecollection Fathers` and `Observablecollection Children`

Comment: In general, the main classes are [MainWindow.xaml](https://github.com/RodKingroo/FatherChild/blob/main/MainWindow.xaml) 
[Child.cs](https://github.com/RodKingroo/FatherChild/blob/main/Models/Child.cs) 
[Father.cs](https://github.com/RodKingroo/FatherChild/blob/main/Models/Father.cs)
[ContextView.cs](https://github.com/RodKingroo/FatherChild/blob/main/ContextView.cs)
[RelayCommand.cs](https://github.com/RodKingroo/FatherChild/blob/main/RelayCommand.cs)
[MainWindow.xaml.cs](https://github.com/RodKingroo/FatherChild/blob/main/MainWindow.xaml.cs)

Comment: @BionicCode Maybe the code is written dirty, but [the code I'm working on](https://github.com/RodKingroo/LabelDataSystem) is done in a hurry, since the deadline for the course work is in 2 days

Comment: *"I don't have enough brains to explain"* - Too sad. I hope you understand that explaining a problem is fundamental if you ask for help. In order to help you need to understand the problem. [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BionicCode OK I'll try 
There is an `Observablecollection Fathers` that stores the `ID-Firstname-Lastname` father.
How to make it so that when loading data from the `child.lbs` file, the `ID` value that is written in the file under `word[4]` is selected in the Combobox field? Item values are spelled out using XAML `<Combobox "ItemsSource = {Binding Fathers}"/>`

Comment: So the ID value at `word[4]` is the FatherID?

Comment: @BionicCode yes

Comment: With all the added code, your question makes more sense now. I assume you want to select the last read Father. Simply iterate over the Fathers collection and filter the items by ID, like `if (father.FatherID == idToSelect)`then set `SelectedFather` to the filtered `father` instance.

Comment: @BionicCode I have also supplemented the text just in case. But I confess honestly I did not understand

Comment: You simply use a for or foreach to loop through the Fathers collection. Then apply the aforementioned if-statement to fileter the father instance by its FatherId property.

Comment: @BionicCode At this action, the error `SelectedFathers gets returns null`

Comment: You should not get it but set it: `SelectedFathers = fatherWithMatchingId;`. Also don't forget to dispose the `StreamReader` instances by wraping them into a using-block. It implements `IDisposable`. If you show your current version (how you loop over the Father items, I can help you to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @BionicCode 4 ur help

Answer ContextWiew.cs:

```cs
using (StreamReader srChild = new StreamReader($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/save/child.lbs")) {
                        lineChild = srChild.ReadLine();
                        while ((lineChild = srChild.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string[] word = lineChild.Split(';');
                            Child c = new Child();
                            c.ChildID = int.Parse(word[0]); 
                            c.Firstname = word[1];
                            p.Secondname = word[2];
                            foreach (Father item in Father)
                            {
                                if (item.FatherID == int.Parse(word[5])) p.Father = item;
                            }


                            Children.Add(c);
                            SelectedChildren = c;
                        }
                        srChild.Close();
                    }
```